# Not able to find element by findby in Firefox but the same element is found in chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using the `FindsBy` annotation in Selenium C# to find elements in a page. The same works in Chrome but Firefox gives an error `NoSuchElementException`.

Any help on what could be the issue.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Instances")]
private IWebElement instanceLink;

[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Gantt View")]
private IWebElement ganttviewLink;

[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "About")]
private IWebElement aboutLink;

[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Help")]
private IWebElement helpLink;
```

Comment: You can find the element using another locator for firefox and append the code with OR statement. So that the code works for both chrome and firefox. Eg: FindsBy Chrome_Locator |OR| Firefox_Locator

Comment: Does the locator work in Firefox when you try it in the browser console? If so have you tried with some kind of wait statement?

Comment: Thanks all. Was able to fix the issue with Wait statement.